# How do I get margin notes to appear on the left?

Tags: positioning, marginpar, marginnote

I'm trying to make a left-sided margin note.

As per the [LaTeX wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting&oldid=2072001#Margin_Notes), I tried using `\reversemarginpar` but that didn't solve anything—it didn't make a margin note at all. I also tried `\marginpar[left text/right text]{%my text}` to no avail. I tried using two other packages, `marginnote` and `mparhack`, but again, those didn't solve my problem.

Maybe there are some things I've missed (perhaps I have to further define something in the preamble?), but I would appreciate an example of how to use a margin note successfully.

Here's some code I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{ulem}

\title{Chapter 13 - Chromosomal Rearrangements and Changes in Chromosome Number}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle

  \section*{\Large Types:}
  \begin{outline}[enumerate]
  \1 Duplications
  \1 Deletions
  \1 Inversions
  \1 Translocations
  \end{outline}

  \textbf{semisterility} $\rightarrow$ diminished fertility of translocation heterozygotes by at least 50\%
  \reversemarginpar{Why does Mendel's 2$\mathrm{^{nd}}$ require viability of offspring?}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem by including at least the errors you get or misalignment problems etc. shown on your compiled document?

Comment: You don't really have the `%` in the `%my text` part, do you? It would make TeX ignore the text and cause an error because of the missing `}`.

Comment: You really need to post your code. `\reversemarginpar` is a command that, when issued, forces all `\marginpar`s created after to be put on the *opposite* side of normal (that is, on the left instead of right for single sided documents, and on the inside edge as opposed to the outside edge for double sided documents). But it sounds like you want to dynamically switch sides as you go along? Like having some margin notes on the left and others on the right? (Lastly, a comment on asking questions: it helps to make your question title more descriptive.)

Comment: @ Martin Scharrer - No, I don't really have the % in my original code.

Comment: @ Wille Wong - No, I do not want to switch sides (have the margin note be left or right as I go along, if that's what you mean). I'd just like the margin note to remain consistently on the left side. I'm sorry if my title is not quite descriptive...

Comment: @ percusse - I don't get any errors when I compile to PDF (I'm using LaTeXilla), but I've posted my code.

Comment: Your minimal example will produce some errors, because you deleted too much information from your actual code: you forgot a `\begin{outline}` command and some first-level item inside the outline. I will correct your minimal example, if that's OK with you.

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina: I was a bit hasty when I was editing my code, so whatever edits you need to make are okay with me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `\reversemarginpar` command cannot be used to typeset the marginal notes; as Willie Wong mentioned in a comment, all `\reversemarginpar` does is to force all subsequent marginal notes to be put on the opposite side. To typeset your marginal notes, you can use the standard `\marginpar` command or, even better, you can use the `\marginnote` command provided by the [marginnote](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package: an example including some of your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\reversemarginpar

\title{\vspace{-0.9in}\uline{Chapter 13 - Chromosomal Rearrangements and Changes in Chromosome Number}}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{}  

\begin{document}

\section*{\Large Types:}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
\1 Duplications
\1 Deletions
\1 Inversions
\1 Translocations
\end{outline}

 \textbf{semisterility} $\rightarrow$ diminished fertility of translocation heterozygotes by at least 50\% \marginnote{Why does Mendel's 2$\mathrm{^{nd}}$ require viability of offspring?}

\end{document}
```

You must compile several times to see the marginal note in its final position.

On a side note, can I ask you why do you use the `outlines` package? It is not part of TeX Live or MiKTeX, and the `enumitem` package (which you are also loading) offers you more possibilities (in my opinion) to customize your lists.

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina: Oh, the reason why I'm using the outlines package is because I'm making an outline and I find it less messy than using having to start a new enumerate for a new sublevel. Since I'm still learning how to use LaTeX, I sort of have this propensity to just keep all the packages I've ever used in my preamble just in case. Whatever I don't use, I delete before I compile the final document.

Comment: @Halime: For outlining, you may want to have a look at `org mode` for `emacs`. It has LaTeX exporting capabilities, so it might be helpful for you.