# Why does inclusion of titlepage mess up margin note placement?

Tags: classicthesis, marginpar, marginnote

**UPDATE**: I managed to reduce the problem to the following (turns out it does not relate to `classicthesis`)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{marginnote}`enter code here`
\usepackage{lipsum, showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
   \lipsum[1]
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

- If I remove `\pagenumbering{arabic}` it works
- If I remove the `titlepage` it works

How can I get both a title page, arabic page numbering and correct margin notes?

---

---

**Original Question**

I use the `classicthesis` package and desire to place `marginnote`s into the larger margin (it's a `twoside`d document). Thus in my preamble I have

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldmarginnote\marginnote
\renewcommand*{\marginnote}[1]{%
   \begingroup%
   \ifodd\value{page}
     \if@firstcolumn\else\reversemarginpar\fi
   \else
     \if@firstcolumn\reversemarginpar\fi
   \fi
   \oldmarginnote{#1}%
   \endgroup%
}
\makeatother
```

Which places the note in the left margin for an even-numbered page, but the space is too large. See the below image
[image]

How do I get it into a reasonable position without messing up the format of the document (I tried some `geometry` related tips, but I wan all margins and such stay the way they are, and simply move the note closer to the body)?

Comment: Please add to your question a *complete* minimal document allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you use the showframe package you will see that the default marginpar area IS on the wide side (directly under the chapter number).

Comment: You can increase the \marginparwidth (it must do its own fixup) but you will move the chapter number with it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I have been strangely unsuccessful in reproducing the problem with a minimal example. I have therefore linked the repository above and I would be greatful if somebody were to take a look at it.

Comment: @oarfish Check the answers here [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14527/how-do-i-get-the-margin-note-to-appear-on-the-left] You only need to issue \reversemarginpar once, maybe just below the chapter titule to preserve the chapter number's position (it's also in a marginpar). Then again at the end of the chapter.

Comment: In adaddition, why are you using '\if@firstcolumn' if your document has only one (column)? Why '\marginnote' if 'classicthesis' sets up all for '\marginpar'

Comment: ´\marginpar` works better but seems to be less customizable than `\marginnote`. Can you elaborate how is `classicthesis` set up for `marginpar`? The snippet was copy-pasted from some place I could not find again and I found it places the notes in the right margin.

Comment: @oarfish Open 'classicthesis.sty' and search for marginpar and graffito. Issuing '\reversemarginpar' only once worked great for me. Just put in below the chapter title and you're good.

Comment: Using the everypage package you can create your own margin notes.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment/216037#216037 for example.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip If I issue `\reversemarginpar` after `\chapter{xyz}`, the chapter number still switches sides and the margin note is on the opposite side of the page.

Comment: @oarfish I tried in on the original template and this didn't happen. Not for the current chapter, but did for the following ones. That's why you need to reverse it again at the end again. Now I'm curious, why would you want the marginal note on the binding side anyway? Book margin is the outer side only.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Regardless of correct typography, I have the problem that the margin notes do not show up in their designated place (illustrated by `showframes`). See the edited question.

Comment: @oarfish Is it same with `marginpar`?

Comment: @PhilipPirrip No, `marginpar` appears to work regardless.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\addtolength{\marginparwidth}{0.5in}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\marginpar{\rule{\marginparwidth}{1pt}}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Two}
\marginpar{\rule{\marginparwidth}{1pt}}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Look at the upper and lower margins. Do you notice the page number running off the page? `classicthesis` assumes certain gloabl options being given down to `typearea`.  I consider this one of the quite many bad decisions the author of classicthesis has made.